# UNC path network connection error 0x80004005

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, windows-server-2016, unc

I'm attempting to connect to Windows Server 2016 Standard Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.1715) via UNC path \\MyServer\F$

I receive the following error after a few moments:

[image: Error Message]

- I am a Domain Admin
- Firewall is off on both machines (the proper ports were in place to allow, but for the sake of troubleshooting, I turned off the FW)
- I can ping MYSERVER via IP address and DNS name
- I can RDP to the DNS name and the IP address
- Default LMHOSTS file
- DNS is set correctly
- NetBIOS setting is Default
- File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks is enabled
- Client for Microsoft Networks is enabled
- We use IPv4 and IPv6
- Both machines are VMWare VMs
- The machine used to connect to the WS2016SE is in a different subnet
- The machine I am using can connect to other systems in the same subnet as the WS2016SE via the UNC path and admin shares
- The same result with IP or DNS name
- I can connect from the WS2016SE server to any other server on the same subnet or different and access the UNC path or admin shares, so the issue is one way
- I have compared the settings of known working systems to the WS2016SE and they are the same
- The settings in vSphere are the same
- Systems in the same subnet cannot access the UNC path or admin shares

What gives, I am at a loss?  Short of rebuilding this server is there anything that anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I was not able to find a resolution.  I ended up completely rebuilding this server to fix the matter.

Moreover, I meticulously went through all the settings and configurations I found in research and listed here and they were all the same.

Serious head scratcher...

Comment: This is one of those "shame on computing" errors soooo time consuming.